# Prove that if the coordinate ring is isomorphic to $k$, then its dimension over $k$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $ \Gamma(V) $ be the coordinate ring of a variety $ V $, that is, it is the quotient ring $ k[x_1, \cdots, x_n]/I(V) $. I want to show that $ \Gamma(V)\simeq k \implies \text{dim}_k \Gamma(V)<\infty $. Is this as trivial as
$$\text{dim}_k \Gamma(V)=\text{dim}_k(k)=1<\infty\ ? $$

Comment: Yes ... ${{{}}}$

Comment: Notice that V will be a point.

Comment: @N.H. Thanks. Why would $V$ have to be just one point?

Comment: By definition $I(V) = \ker k[x_1, \dots, x_n] \to k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I(V) \cong k$. So $I(V)$ is a maximal ideal, which corresponds bijectively to points by the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: @N.H. Thanks again. I am actually trying to prove the equivalence of three properties. I am stuck on proving that c) implies a). See the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253565/prove-the-equivalence-of-a-v-is-a-point-b-gammav-simeq-k-and-c-di
Do you think you can help me? I need to prove that $V$ is a point without assuming that $\Gamma(V)\cong k$.